# How to display ALL variable names in the plot browser window of a plot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have just figured out how to display variable names in the plot browser window in a plot in matlab. However, it displays only up to 50 names at a time. I cannot find any option to view names of all the variables. I am using the following command:

```
%let ens be an array of size 120X1800
plot(ens','displayname','ens'); plotbrowser on;
```

Comment: This issue have been up before in [matlab answers](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/161404-how-can-i-browse-a-large-amount-of-curves-in-plotbrowser-r2014b). I think there is a bug report on this as well.

Comment: Just saw it. Thank you very much!